# PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest: Possible to parse this XML response?

Tags: xml, powershell, invoke-webrequest

I get a XML response from the REST interface which looks the following. I'd like to only get "OK" back but this hashtag makes it not straight forward.

```
xmlns #text

http://ucmacs81/OMWebService/ OK
```

[Link to Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q99Bn.png)

Code I'm using to parse the XML:

```
return ([xml]$Response.Content).String
```

Is there a possability to escape this hashtag somehow that I only get the "OK"?

Comment: Why not `([xml]$Response.Content).'#text'` or `([xml]$Response.Content).InnerText`?

Comment: Ok, that's simple. I just couldn't figure it how to get to the OK text. Both solutions work.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the property directly using member access `.` and single quoting the property name.

```
([xml]$Response.Content).'#text'
```

The `#text` value can also be retrieved by the property `InnerText`.

```
([xml]$Response.Content).InnerText
```